# Adding two numerical variables

Tags: math-operators

I defined two variables x and y. If I want to define a new coordinate, I can easily operate them. In this case the output for (A) would be (-1,3). However if I want to draw an ellipse, the output of the radius is always the last variable and not their sum. So instead of radius x+y=3 I get radius y=2.

```
\newcommand\x{1}
\newcommand\y{2}

\coordinate (A) at (\x-\y,\x+\y);
\draw (0,0) arc(90:180:\x+\y cm and \x+\y cm);
```

Comment: Using `arc(90:180:\x cm+\y cm and \x cm+\y cm);` should help I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` which allows to properly do maths in such expressions. `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` additionally takes care of units. Example:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\x{1.5cm}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\y{0.2cm}
        \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) arc(90:180: {\x + \y}   and {\x + \y} );
    \end{tikzpicture}
```